# Split a comma separated list and copy the rest of the info into rows below

Tags: excel, vba, string, split

I have a spreadsheet with 19940 rows and 37 columns. In the email column there are cells that have 1 email address, cells that have 0 email addresses, and cells that have multiple email addresses separated by a comma. I need to take the cells with multiple email addresses and split them up into a new row with the rest of the data duplicating into that row. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJlHM.png).

I found a similar post to mine, however trying the code in the answer made Excel stop responding. I've tried it multiple times and every time it ends up not responding. The code I'm using is:

```
Sub SplitPartsRows()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim arrParts() As String
Dim partNum As Long
'## For the actual file i use columns A:AK, and column AC contains the Corresponding Parts ##

Set rng = Range("A1:AK19940") '## Modify as needed ##'

r = 2
Do While r <= rng.Rows.Count
    '## Split the value in column AC (29) by commas, store in array ##
    arrParts = Split(rng(r, 29).Value, ",")
    '## If there's more than one item in the array, add new lines ##
    If UBound(arrParts) >= 1 Then '## corrected this logic for base 0 array
        rng(r, 29).Value = arrParts(0)

        '## Iterate over the items in the array ##
        For partNum = 1 To UBound(arrParts)
            '## Insert a new row ##'
            '## increment the row counter variable ##
            r = r + 1
            rng.Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            '## Copy the row above ##'
            rng.Rows(r).Value = rng.Rows(r - 1).Value

            '## update the part number in the new row ##'
            rng(r, 29).Value = Trim(arrParts(partNum))

            '## resize our range variable as needed ##
            Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Columns.Count)

        Next

    End If
'## increment the row counter variable ##
r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: The code above works when I use sample sets of the data such as 5, 50, 100, 500, 1000, and 2500 rows, but when I try to run it in the main set of 19940 rows my excel stops responding.

Comment: I know it won't help you, but thanks for your sample, it was exactly what I was searching for (just 200 rows for my case).
As for your issue, maybe you should try to copy all new rows to a new sheet. This way, you just keep the initial range ( and don't have to extend it), maybe your excel hang because of the huge range ?